# Trouble using command prompt to mount a network drive

Tags: windows-7, command-line, mount

When I tried to mount the drive with the following command:

```
net use x:\\folder\Sharename
```

I get the following error:

> "System error 67 has occurred the network name cannot be found"

When I try to do the following it works - but of course mounts the drive with a random assigned name:

```
pushd \\folder\Sharename
```

I know I am missing something here. When I navigate to `\\folder\Sharename` in explorer it works, I have permissions to access it and the network path is reachable.

I have deduced it's either a syntax error, or I'm simply trying to use the command wrongly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using the command line mount a network drive

```
net use x:\\folder\Sharename
```

The syntax of the above command is incorrect.

It should be:

```
net use x: \\folder\Sharename
```

Note the additional <kbd>space</kbd>.

---

#### Syntax

```
NET USE [devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD] [/SAVECRED] [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]
```

> Map to the current user's home directory as specified in the users
>   Active Directory record:
>
> ```
> NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME
> ```
>
> Set defaults:
>
> ```
> NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
> ```

...

> Examples:
>
> ```
>  NET USE [driveletter:] \\ComputerName\ShareName /PERSISTENT:YES
>  NET USE [driveletter:] \\ComputerName\ShareName\folder1\folder2 /PERSISTENT:No
>  NET USE H: /Home
>  NET USE J: \\MainServer\Users\%Username%
>  NET USE W: \\MainServer\GroupShare /Persistent:No
>  NET USE \\MainServer\SharedPrinter
> ```

Source [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net use](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html) - Map a drive letter to a remote server/share.

Comment: wow thank you. I move to close the question based on stupid question lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
net use x: \\computer name\share name
```

You need to separate the drive letter from the network share with a space.